# Load png into a SWFBitmap

Tags: php, libming

I can't load a dbl file into a SWFBitmap object.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$png = file_get_contents("/home/damiano/a.dbl");
$img = new SWFBitmap($png);
die();
?>
```

That throws me out a:

```
Fatal error: opening bitmap file failed in /var/www/misterjoke/ming.php on line 3
```

From shell I simply converted the file this way:

```
png2dbl a.png
```

And the print of the file_get_contents returns a binary string as expected. What's wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what you can find on http://ch.php.net/manual/de/class.swfbitmap.php

This doesnt work:

```
<?php 
 $f = $s->addFill(new SWFBitmap( file_get_contents("image.jpg"))); 
?>
```

But this will works fine:

```
<?php 
 $f = $s->addFill(new SWFBitmap((fopen('image.jpg','rb'))); 
?>
```

Comment: Yup, that's it thanks. But unfortunately the flv file coming out seems to be corrupted: players can't play it and gstreamer libraries yell...